# Probability of Union and Intersection of Events

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

A, B and C are three independent events such that, $P(A) = \frac12, P(B) = \frac13, P(C) = \frac17$

Find $P((A\cup B)\cap C)$.

**My Answer:**

$$P((A\cup B)\cap C) = P((A\cup B))\cdot P(C) = \frac23 \cdot \frac17 =\frac2{21}$$

**But:**

$$P((A\cup B)\cap C) =P((A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)) = \frac1{14} + \frac1{21} - \frac1{14}\cdot \frac1{21} = \frac{34}{14\cdot 21} $$

Why are the two methods giving different answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A \cap C$ and $B \cap C$ are not independent.

We have $P(A \cap B \cap C)=\frac1{42}$.

Hence, the second computation should be $$\frac1{14}+\frac1{21}-\frac1{42}=\frac1{14}+\frac1{42}=\frac{4}{42}=\frac{2}{21}$$

Comment: Hi many thanks. Can you share some materials for this? How do we know that A intersection C and B intersection C are not independent?

Comment: Suppose they are independent, then your computation would reach a contradiction. I just work it out from the definition.

Comment: But still, can you share some links or materials? I still cannot wrap my head around this

Comment: Is it that P((A∩C) U (B∩C)) == P(A∩C) + P(B∩C) - P(A∩C∩B) ??

Comment: yes, we use that formula that you just stated. not sure how helpful is this [link](https://www.siyavula.com/read/maths/grade-11/probability/10-probability-02).

Comment: I know about dependence and independence. What I am looking for is how it happens in a special case like this, where 3 events are independent but their intersections are dependent.

Comment: @DomJo If $\mathcal R = \{A, B, C, \ldots, H\}$ is a collection of mutually  independent events and $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are two _disjoint_ or mutually exclusive subsets of $\mathcal R$, then any Boolean function of the events in $\mathcal A$ and any Boolean function of the events in $\mathcal B$ are independent events. For  example, $A\cup B^c$ and $(C\cap D)^c$ are independent events. But if  $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$  are _not disjoint_,  then independence needn't hold, specifically not for  $\mathcal A = \{A,C\}$ and $\mathcal B = \{B,C\}$ since they have $C$ in common.